# CSS "preload" animation

Tags: javascript, css

In CSS I wrote some dirty code for a transition, that loads 24 different mask images. The first time it's played, there is lag as it loads, but If I have a div "preload" it, ie play it at page load, it seems to be cached, thus won't lag again, so I tried to do this like so:

```
<div class='trans' style='z-index:1;height:100%;width:100%;overflow:hidden;visibility:visibile;'/>
```

Which works, BUT, when I try hide it with display:none; the animation won't show until it's loaded. Same with visibility.
Is there a better way to do this?

Any help appreciated.

```
@keyframes transit {
    0%   {
  -webkit-mask-image: url('img0.png');
  mask-image: url('img0.png');}

      4%   {
  -webkit-mask-image: url('img1.png');
  mask-image: url('img1.png');}

      8%   {
  -webkit-mask-image: url('img2.png');
  mask-image: url('img2.png');}
  ...

 .trans{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-mask-position: center center;
  mask-position: center center;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-size: cover;
  -webkit-mask-size: cover;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation-direction: reverse;
  animation: transit 2s;
}
...

function menu(){

$('body').addClass('trans');
setTimeout(function() {
  $('body').removeClass('trans');
}, 2000);
}
```

Comment: I think on a higher level there must be a way more efficient solution to this. However if you need a quick shortcut and display:none or visibility:hidden are causing you grief you could try re-positioning the element off-screen during the initial downloading phase.

Comment: wow, that's such a quick and dirty solution I can't believe I didn't think of it myself. Still hoping  something better will come along though

Comment: try something like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content for example `<link rel="preload" href="image.png" as="image">` since its a blocking element, positioning them above your css, will make sure they loaded before.

Comment: I saw that page, but will said images still be preloaded in the animation itself?

Comment: @Dementic make it an answer and I'll mark it

Comment: As long as it's the same URL, the browser considers it preloaded/cached, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content
You could use HTML elements to preload your images,
Since elements in the head are blocking, make sure you add your images BEFORE your CSS
as so:

```html
<link rel="preload" href="image.png" as="image">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
```